# What does exec 3<&1 do?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, file-descriptors, exec

I understand that `exec` can do I/O redirection on the current shell, but I only sees usage like:

```
exec 6<&0   # Link file descriptor #6 with stdin.
            # Saves stdin.

exec 6>&1   # Link file descriptor #6 with stdout.
            # Saves stdout.
```

From that I understand that `<` is for input stream, `>` is for output stream. So what does `exec 3<&1` do?

PS: I found this from [Bats source code](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats/blob/ddd03ab8526d59ab5ef6d9b3604d3359513af39e/libexec/bats-exec-test#L269)

Comment: @Gnouc is obviously correct, but it should be noted that *`exec 3<&1`* differs from *`3<&1`* in that the latter will affect a single command whereas the former affects the current shell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From `bash manpage`:

```
Duplicating File Descriptors
       The redirection operator

              [n]<&word

       is used to duplicate input file descriptors.  If word expands to one or
       more  digits,  the file descriptor denoted by n is made to be a copy of
       that file descriptor.  If the digits in word  do  not  specify  a  file
       descriptor  open for input, a redirection error occurs.  If word evalu‐
       ates to -, file descriptor n is closed.  If n  is  not  specified,  the
       standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.

       The operator

              [n]>&word

       is  used  similarly  to duplicate output file descriptors.  If n is not
       specified, the standard output (file descriptor 1)  is  used.   If  the
       digits  in word do not specify a file descriptor open for output, a re‐
       direction error occurs.  As a special case, if n is omitted,  and  word
       does not expand to one or more digits, the standard output and standard
       error are redirected as described previously.
```

I did some debugs with `strace`:

```
sudo strace -f -s 200 -e trace=dup2 bash redirect.sh
```

For `3<&1`:

```
dup2(3, 255)                            = 255
dup2(1, 3)                              = 3
```

For `3>&1`:

```
dup2(1, 3)                              = 3
```

For `2>&1`:

```
dup2(1, 2)                              = 2
```

It seems that `3<&1` do exactly the same as `3>&1`, duplicating stdout to file descriptor 3.

Comment: From the manpage, I would expect it to throw a redirection error because stdout is not open for input. However, it really does duplicate stdin (which is &0). How?

Comment: @orion: Internally, the same `dup2()` syscall is used for any kind of file descriptor; bash's `x>&y` vs `x<&y` is just syntax sugar. Also, when stdio is attached to a tty, the tty device is very often opened for read+write and just duplicated from 0 to 1 and 2.

Comment: @grawity so `exec 3<&1` is same as `exec >&3` ?

Comment: No, but it is the same as `exec 3>&1`.